# How to call non static methods from Action<T> delegate in C#

Tags: c#, generics, static, delegates

Since I am writing a generic concept for some action to be perform, I need to call some non static method in the Action delegate. Also, none of them are static in my code. But still I can't call the non static method inside the Action  definition.
Here's my code-

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<object>> m_dicUndoRedoAction = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();
m_dicUndoRedoAction.Add("DeleteClass", DeleteClassFromeNode );
```

and Here's the definition of DeleteClass

```
private Action<object> DeleteClassFromeNode =
  data =>
  {
    Tuple<itemType1, itemType2> items = data as Tuple<itemType1, itemType2>;
    if (items != null && items.Item2 != null)
    {
      DeleteClass(items.Item2); // This is my non static method in the same class.
    }
  };
```

and Here's how I call the delegate

```
private void Undo_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  object temp;
  if (UndoRedoAction.DoUndo(out temp))
  {
    m_dicUndoRedoAction["DeleteClass"].Invoke(temp);
  }
}
```

as compiler says

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'DeleteClassFromeNode'

I have also reviewed MSDN reference for [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) article, but nowhere MS has mentioned whether, Action is implicitly static, or am I going some wrong way ?
I also looked up on some nonstatic call from static methods, but none of them were satisfactory explained.
I would appreciate it if anyone provide its low level explanation.

> *On response to Peter explanation*

Though initializers run before the constructor has completed, that doesn't make it to trigger the delegate in between the constructor execution. Even if you will look up its assembly code in ILDASM, it shows the real action Field as non static, but cached anonymous delegate object as static. Why this different behavior by compiler ?

[image]

Comment: `private Action<object> DeleteClassFromeNode = ...` seems somewhat strange. Why can you not simply make it a method, like `private void DeleteClassFromeNode(object data) { ... }`? `m_dicUndoRedoAction.Add("DeleteClass", DeleteClassFromeNode );` would still compile, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Hi hvd, Its coz I generally use anonymous fields in my code. and obviously that is not against the csc rules.

Comment: Your code is violating a C# language rule.  It isn't very visible, but in order to initialize the lambda, the compiler needs to use *this*.  It is captured, required because DeleteClass() is an instance method.  And you can't use *this* to initialize fields, the constructor hasn't finished running yet by the time the field gets initialized.  You must move the initialization into the constructor.  Not your preferred "style" probably, but necessary.

Comment: @hvd Please write that as an answer. It is clearly the best solution. To Rohit Prakash: The arrow `=>` will still be converted into a method by the compiler. In your case it is much better to use the name `DeleteClassFromeNode` for the method. And the body of a named method (non-static) may refer the other instance members of `this`, of course. As hvd said, the "method group" `DeleteClassFromeNode` converts implicitly to the type `Action<object>`. Maybe the type of the method parameter `data` should be some `Tuple<,>` and not just `object`? Note that `Action<in T>` is *contravariant* in `T`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, but I do try not to post something as an answer if it doesn't answer the question. Peter Duniho's answer is the correct one for the question that's asked, even if I suspect that the question that's asked is not the question that should be asked.

Comment: Thanks, Mr passant and others. 
**in order to initialize the lambda, the compiler needs to use _this_ **. This is what, better explains the low level architect of lamda expressions. 
Btw, there's still one doubted behavior of compiler is, Why the field has two instances in its msil code as one is marked static, other not. (I mean, why not both) ?

Comment: Note that you can write `m_dicUndoRedoAction["DeleteClass"](temp);` instead of `m_dicUndoRedoAction["DeleteClass"].Invoke(temp);`.

Comment: Regarding your question about the IL code: You made that IL from *another* version of the C# code which the compiler was happy with. Since every instance of your class has its own instance field `DeleteRootClass` and that field really has the same value for all the instances, and since delegate objects are immutable, the compiler has chosen to *cache* that delegate object on a static field. Then when the initialization of a new instance of your class runs, it is checked if a delegate instance is already in the static cache field. If yes, the same delegate instance is re-used.

Answer (score 6):

Just as the compiler is telling you, you are prohibited from using non-static members in an initializer. This is because initializers run before the constructor has completed, and so it is not necessarily safe to use non-static members.

Instead, just perform the initialization in the constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
    DeleteClassFromeNode = data =>
    {
        Tuple<itemType1, itemType2> items = data as Tuple<itemType1, itemType2>;
        if (items != null && items.Item2 != null)
        {
          DeleteClass(items.Item2); // This is my non static method in the same class.
        }
    };

    // Other initialization code can go here (or before...whatever is most appropriate)
}
```

Comment: While this works, it is better to simply make `DeleteClassFromeNode` an ordinary (named, not anonymous) instance method on `MyClass`. So `void DeleteClassFromeNode(object data) { ... }`. Certainly inside the body of that method you can call the non-static member `DeleteClass`. See comment by hvd under the question for more. The only reason for having it as a delegate field is if you plan to reassign the field later, with `=`, or `+=` or `-=`. Are you? If not, change into ordinary method (or at least declare the field `readonly`).